# Oracle Database with autofs

Tags: oracle, automount, autofs

We run our oracle databases (11 & 12) on NFS on Redhat 6.  We do not use ASM.  Is it acceptable to use autofs for all of the various oracle files?

Thanks,

Al

Comment: What would be the gain?

Comment: In my experience, that could be very painful. Oracle (certainly RMAN) is known to be very picky with the mount settings that were negotiated. Better check the supported configuration matrix.

Comment: OT: Is this part of some fail-over solution? Just beware that Oracle might have speficic requirements (for example locking) and not every NFS server implementation is certified. I doubt that the default Linux one is.

Comment: We have some clone databases that require the production archive logs on occasion, but I don't want it mounted all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you couldn't.  That said, unless you have a specific need for some feature of autofs mounts such as LDAP or multi-mount mappings, then it seems like an unnecessary step.